# Unexpected token on line 17:115 reactjs

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-dom, unexpected-token

The code runs perfectly fine when i run `npm start`. Website does get render on browser but it still shows an error in my terminal.

```
Line 17:115: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
```

I already did a search related to this problem. The solution, I get from most of the website is that people forget to put `componentDidMount` in Class component but as you can seen in my code it already present in Class componenet.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  List
} from './CardList';
// import {Data} from './data';
import {
  SearchBox
} from './SearchBox';
import './App.css'

export class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      "Data": [],
      "searchfield": ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
LINE 17---> fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(Response => Response.json()).then(users => this.setState({Data: users}));
  }

  Searchchange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      searchfield: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const filterrobot = this.state.Data.filter(Data => {
      return Data.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
    })
    if (this.state.Data.length === 0) {
      return <h1 className='tc'>Loagding</h1>
    } else {
      return (
       <div className='tc'>
          <h1 className='f1'>SEARCH PICTURES></h1>
          <SearchBox secondchange = {this.Searchchange}/>
          <List Data={filterrobot}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```